# Roots of $z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ lie inside $|z|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Let $P(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}z+a_{n}$, and suppose $|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|\leq 1$. Find the least $R>0$ for which all the roots of $P(z)$ always lie inside $|z|\leq R$.

$P(z)=z^n-1$ has root $z=1$, so $R\geq 1$.

For $|z|=R>1$, we have $$|z^n|=R^n\geq R^n(|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|)> R^{n-1}|a_1|+R^{n-2}|a_2|\cdots+|a_n|\geq |a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n|,$$

so $z^n$ and $P(z)$ has the same number of roots inside $|z|<R$, which is $n$. Since this holds for any $R>1$, $P(z)$ has all $n$ roots in $|z|\leq 1$.

Question: Is there a way to avoid Rouche's?

Comment: @arbautjc I like it! I'm just wondering if there's a way to avoid it in this case, since the problem looks quite elementary (while Rouche's has an advanced proof).

Comment: If $z$ is a root and if $|z|>1$, then $z^n=-a_1z^{n-1}-\ldots-a_n$ yields $|z|^n\leq  |z|^{n-1}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown in your argument that $$|z^n|>|a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n|,$$ for any $z>R$. This inequality alone is enough to show that such a $z$ cannot be a root of the polynomial, as such a root must have equality on both sides.